# Does UIViewController's presentModalViewController:animated: retain the modal controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

This has implications on the way I interact with my modal controllers. When I first started out in iOS development, I assumed that `UIViewController` *did not* retain the modally presented view. Well, really it was more like I had no reason to assume it *did* retain them.  This left me with fairly awkward attempts at releasing them when I knew they would have finished their dismissal animations:

```
_myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self. present modalViewController:_myViewController animated:YES];
/* 
Some stuff, then in a different method all together,
probably as the result of a delegate callback or something...
*/
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimiated:YES];
[_myViewController performSelector:@selector(release) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
```

Then, I saw the `modalViewController` property of `UIViewController` and thought, "Man, I hope it retains that property when a modal view controller is presented."  Sure enough, I logged the retain count on several of these attempts and noticed a general increase immediate after the call to `presentModalViewController:animated:` (I know, retain counts are not a perfect metric). So, somewhere along the line, I have started using a much nicer pattern where I assume that any controller object I present modally is retained by the presenting controller.  This lets me write the standard present code:

```
UIViewController* myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
[myViewController release]; // <- Fire and forget!
```

Now, of course, there is no awkwardness: no need to wait for an animation to finish, or even keep a reference to the presented controller if I don't need it. I can blindly dismiss it later and not worry about leaking. I like it.

I have logged many a dealloc in my modally presented controllers and they are always called precisely when I want, which leads me to feel confident in my approach: `UIViewController`'s `presentModalViewController:animated:` retains the presented controller as the `modalViewController` property.

But, and this is the meat of this question, I realized that I can't confirm this as ***documented*** behavior. And if it's not documented, I should not feel nearly as safe as I do, because Apple makes no promises about the longevity of undocumented behavior.  The `modalViewController` property is publicly `readonly`, so I can only assume a retain behind the scenes, and the documentation on `presentModalViewController:animated:` says only:

> Sets the modalViewController property to the specified view controller.

"Sets" could be `assign` or `retain`. Nothing I read blatantly confirms or denies my position. Since this is an assumption I make often, I would really love it if someone could point out a fact that I have missed somewhere in the bowels of documentation to put my mind at ease about the legitimacy of this practice.

**EDIT:** In the ebb and flow of day-to-day life in the iOS SDK, I found myself in the header for UIViewController and started reading some of it. I gleaned some useful info that reminded me of this question and I decided to post it, in the event some future user stumbles upon this question and wants as much info as possible to satisfy their paranoia of a very standard practice.  The little morsel is simply this, from the @interface ivar block in UIViewController.h:

```
UIViewController *_childModalViewController;
```

As opposed to these other declarations:

```
UIViewController *_parentViewController; // Nonretained
NSHashTable      *_childViewControllers; // Nonretained
```

The comments seem to explicitly state what is *not* retained. By virtue of a lack of comment on the modal view controller ivar declaration, it would seem it *is* retained.

Comment: same question here. anybody may help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The memory management rules of Objective-C define the behaviour, so it doesn't need to expressly document that it retains the modal view controller.  If an object needs to keep a passed object around after the method has finished executing, it *will* retain the object *unless otherwise specified*.

So in this case, you should just pass the view controller to `presentModalViewController:animated:` and then release it (or use autorelease).

This applies everywhere in Objective-C.  If an object takes another object as method input, you *never* have to retain that object on its behalf.

As requested in the comments, if you read Apple's [documentation on memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), then you'll find the [section on Weak References](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1044135), which states:

> **Important**: In Cocoa, references to
>   table data sources, outline view
>   items, notification observers, and
>   delegates are all considered weak (for
>   example, an NSTableView object does
>   not retain its data source and the
>   NSApplication object does not retain
>   its delegate). The documentation *only
>   describes exceptions to this
>   convention.*

This actually states that this is a convention in itself and that exceptions will be stated in the documentation, however, going to the documentation for `NSTableView` and looking at the `setDataSource:` method, we see:

> **Discussion** In a managed memory
>   environment, the receiver maintains a
>   weak reference to the data source
>   (that is, it does not retain the data
>   source, see Communicating With
>   Objects). After setting the data
>   source, this method invokes tile.
>
> This method raises an
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException if
>   anObject doesn’t respond to either
>   numberOfRowsInTableView: or
>   tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:.

Comment: How about any of the delegate / weak ref storing methods? They take objects as method inputs, keep them around, and you *do* have to retain the object on its behalf. If you could show me where, in the docs, it states that all weak ref storing methods will explicitly state the lack of retain, then I would be happy.

Comment: Your first citation seems to set up a specific set of instances where weak-refs are default, and strong refs will be noted as exceptions. It does not tell me that strong refs are default, and weak-refs will be noted as exceptions, which is what you seem to imply with your statement: "*If an object needs to keep a passed object around after the method has finished executing, it will retain the object unless otherwise specified.*"

Comment: Also, I realize I'm being extremely nit-picky here. I appreciate your thoughts and I agree with you that it does make total sense as far as convention is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm good question!  I'm not totally sure about your assumptions.  The property in question is defined in the docs as:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *modalViewController
```

As you point out, it doesn't specify how it is stored.

This document:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

in fact, states that if retain/assign/copy is not specified, that assign is the default behavior.

---

I've also read d11wtq's reply, but am not sure I totally agree. I agree about the conventions about obj-c memory management, but there are many cases where framework methods don't retain properties (think weak references, delegates, etc).  I hope somebody can confirm your assumptions.

Comment: I agree with you on the weak references point. I could see this theoretically going both ways, which is why I would sleep better with solid verdict.

Comment: If an object does not retain an object, but needs it to stay around, the behaviour should be documented as such.  Obviously for third-party frameworks I can't guarantee this since it's up to the developers of the framework to document it, but within the scope of apple products, exceptions to the rule 100% should be documented.

Comment: That document you link to is talking about declared properties and is not related to this question.  The user is asking about `presentModalViewController:animated:`.  That is just a method... not a declared property (by the way, just in case you think it was me who downvoted, it wasn't ;))  The retain/assign stuff on properties only applies to setters.  It does nothing for readonly properties.

Answer (score 2):

sure it's documented. And by the way, I doesn't know the other way :D
I use the alloc-present-release method since I started iOS programming 1.5 years ago

You can find the sample code if you launch Xcode and create a "Utility Application".
In the (Apple provided) code should be:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
controller.delegate = self;

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess iPortable's answer gives you what you want - a peace in your mind when you are releasing the view controller in that way.

By the way, a part of the reasons why printing out retainCount is not a good debugging strategy is because where you put NSLog or breakpoint may not be the right place to look at the retain count. Some retaining or releasing may follow AFTER you check its retain count caused by the event you are interested in.

So if you really want to know what the retain count would be since an event, just override -(id) release and -(void) release method and print logs there, and count yourself. Of course, you must call superclass's retain/release at the end of your methods. In this way, for example, you can get a very clear answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing a **animation** while presenting the modal view controller like

```
[viewController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presentViewController completion");
}];
/*DON'T RELEASE IF THERE IS ANIMATION*/
//[modalViewController release];
```

it's not a good idea to release the object. Instead put a callback to the calling class from which the class can be released.

If you are **NOT using animation** then you may release it immediately after presenting it modally as follows.

```
   [viewController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:NO completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presentViewController completion");
}];

[modalViewController release];/*YOU MAY RELEASE MODAL VIEW CONTROLLER IMMEDIATELY*/
```